# ggplot2 barplot with xlim() cuts off the first and last bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

while plotting a simple barplot with ggplot2, if specifying the xlim() to limit the plot to a specific range, the first and last bar are cut off and all is displayed is part of the error bar (see example).
How can I solve this?

Thanks all!

```
df=data.frame(mean=c(1,4,2,3,1,4,2,3,1,4,2,3,1,4,2,3,1,4,2,3,1,4,2,3,
1,4,2,3,1,4,2,3,1,4,2,3,1,4,2,3),stdev=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.3,
0.4,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,
0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4))

ggplot(df,aes(x=seq(from=1,to=nrow(df)), y=mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(
      ymin=mean-stdev,
      ymax=mean+stdev
    ), 
    width=.2,
    position=position_dodge(.9)
  ) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) + 
  xlim(10,30)
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: Set `xlim(10.5, 29.5)`

Comment: Actually `xlim(9.55, 30.45)` is enough to account for (half of) the width of the bars which by default is .9.